# Why can't strip remove the space in this string?

Tags: python

```
s = '种草 ​'
print(len(s))
s = s.strip()
print(len(s))
```

And the output for both is '4'. It seems the space takes up 2 characters and can't be removed by the strip() function. It's a Chinese space and can't be removed by the strip function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a usual unicode space. you can remove it like this.

```
s = '种草 ​'
print(len(s))
s = s.strip(u'\u200b').strip()
print(len(s))
```

Answer (score 5):

`strip` removes spaces from both ends of a string.

```
>>> s = '种草 ​'
>>> ord(s[-1])
8203
>>> ord(s[-2])
32
>>> ord(' ')
32
```

The last character here is not a space character. The second last character is a space.

Comment: Then how to deal with this situation to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it's not well-looking solution, but it will strip **all** non-printable and whitespace characters:

```
from itertools import takewhile

check = lambda c: not c.isprintable() or c.isspace()

result = s[len(tuple(takewhile(check, s))): -len(tuple(takewhile(check, reversed(s))))]
# OR to not waste memory for tuple
result = s[sum(1 for _ in takewhile(check, s)): -sum(1 for _ in takewhile(check, reversed(s)))]
```

Here I used [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) to get all non-printable ([`str.isprintable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable)) and space ([`str.isspace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace)) chars from the start of string. Then using [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) (or [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) in option with list comprehension) i got amount of such as chars and used this amount as start index in string slice. To get end index I used same method, but with reversed ([`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)) string.